# Vaadin component added twice for some reason

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm developing a webapplication in the Vaadin framework.
I have according to me a very strange behaviour in my application that some of you hopefully are familiar with or in other ways knows how to work around.

This is the relevant code:

```
        AbstractComponent horizontalLine = Cf.horizontalLine();
        horizontalLine.addStyleName("m2m-horizontal-line-list-separator");
        horizontalLine.setWidth("100%");
        horizontalLine.setParent(null);
        SVerticalLayout spacer = Cf.vLayout(new SLabel(""));
        spacer.setMargin(true);

        CssLayout cssLayout = new CssLayout();

        cssLayout.addStyleName("m2m-css-style");
        cssLayout.addComponent(inventoryFilterPanel);
        cssLayout.addComponent(horizontalLine);
        cssLayout.addComponent(simCardTable);

        Panel basePanel = new Panel("");
        basePanel.setContent(cssLayout);
        basePanel.addStyleName("m2m-base-panel");
        basePanel.setSizeFull();
        basePanel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();

        addStyleName("m2m-tab-main-view");
        setMargin(false);
        addComponent(basePanel);
        setExpandRatio(basePanel, 1);
```

EDIT: Adding relevant CSS:

```
.m2m-horizontal-line-list-separator {
    width: 97%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.m2m-css-style {
    margin: 10px;
}

.v-panel-content-m2m-base-panel .v-verticallayout  {
    min-width: 100%;
}

.m2m-tab-main-view {
/**Didn't have any CSS inside it*/
}
```

EDIT 2: Image showing the problem

[image]

EDIT 3: Screen shot of the generated markup from Firebug

[image]

In the markup you see a: 
-Panel containing a CssLayout. 
-Inside the CssLayout we have the first instance of the line, which shouldn't be there, which also is marked. 
-The following div is the VerticalLayout which contains the filterPanel. 
-Next we have the line, the one that is correct, and 
-finally we have the table.

The abstract component 'horizontalLine' works as a divider to divide the filterPanel component and the table. According to the code it's added once, however, for some weird reason in the browser it's added two times. One instance is added where I want it to be and another is added in the upper top of the cssLayout, above everything else! Crazy right!? =P

I have no idea why this is. As you see from the code there's only one instance of it, and it's only added once.... Anyone have any idea of what is going on?

Thanks!
/Max

Comment: May be your add another to inventoryFilterPanel component?

Comment: @Yury Well now that would have been embarrassing, wouldn't it..? =)
But no, the line is only added once throughout the code... =\

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of hard to say what's going on from the code you provided. My guess would be that the CSS that actually renders the horizontal line bleeds over into some other component/layout or you have an error in your CSS rules.

Anyhow, please add the relevant parts of your CSS to the question unless you already figured it out.

HTH,
/Jonatan

Comment: Hello Jonathan, and thank you for your answer! I've added what I assume would be all relevant code. If you feel like something is missing please tell me!

Comment: Can't find anything wrong with your code and my guess was wrong now that I see what the DOM looks like. Are you sure that the code you posted is actually the code that generates the layout? Try to isolate the problem in a small application, that usually helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code I posted is the relevant code. Looking at the CSS and the Firebug printout they seem to correlate perfectly. There are four (should be three) components in the CssLayout in the image and there's four div's in the CssLayout in the printout. Was this what you wondered?

Answer (score 0):

Only now I notice that you set your layout as new Panel layout. In your CSS style "m2m-base-panel" your may be do not overwrite some of Panel base styles with draw borders around Panel content layout.

```
//This CSS part draw around Panel content layout border, 
//with I think you see "upper top of the cssLayout"        
.v-panel-content {
    border: 1px solid #BABFC0;
    //Some other style depends on with Vaadin theme you use
}
```

Try add to your panel style `Runo.PANEL_LIGHT` or `Reindeer.PANEL_LIGHT`, this should solve your problem.

Comment: You're asking if the upper line in fact could be the upper part of the Panel border..? Then no, it's a good guess, but that's not it. The border is there also, right above the line. I've added an image showing the problem.

Comment: Can you inspect this element in browser and add "browser source code" of this line component to see with style were added? If style of this line is same with bottom line, that add inventoryFilterPanel component code, may be something wrong inside it.

Comment: Strange. OK, lets try do next. First of all try to play with components position on layout by setting position index.

cssLayout.addComponent(inventoryFilterPanel,0);
cssLayout.addComponent(horizontalLine,2);
cssLayout.addComponent(simCardTable,1);

Comment: If "line" will shown in wrong place, try to use, for example VerticalLayout instead CssLayout.
If this will not work try to do somethisg like this:

cssLayout.addComponent(new Label("test test"));
cssLayout.addComponent(horizontalLine);
cssLayout.addComponent(new Label("test test"));
cssLayout.addComponent(horizontalLine);
cssLayout.addComponent(new Label("test test"));

In this case we will figure out if this duplicated line "connected" to your components on not.

Waiting your answer.

Comment: Hey Yury. I tried using index, setting filter.index(0), line.index(1) and table.index(2) will cause the second line to be painted right next to the first line instead of on top filter. I tried switching to another component, new Label("TESTING"), this also came up twice, so it shouldn't have anything to do with the line component (plus I've used it in other instances). switching to vLayout insted of CSS won't help because vLayout was the original layout when I switched to CSS and the problem was there then as well.. =\

Comment: OK. Lets try to create another "line" component instead exist. Try this one:
HorizontalLayout lineLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
lineLayout.addStyleName(Runo.LAYOUT_DARKER);
lineLayout.setHeight("1px");
lineLayout.setWidth("100%");

Comment: I don't know what Runo.LAYOUT_DARKER is supposed to do but this only generates a transparent hLayout in the view, plus it too gets duplicated... =P
This is without a doubt one of the weirdest problems I've had working with this framework so far...

Comment: I want to thank you for trying to help me, but I've chosen the easy way out... by adding the horizontal line in the filterPanel component instead the problem is eradicated. It's not what I'd hope for but it has to work for now. Have lots of other things to focus on also... =)